# register gitlab-runner to gitlab from docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

i am new to docker. i run gitlab ce container with this command:

```
docker run --detach --hostname localhost --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --name gitlab --restart always gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

and this container work good

i run gitlab-runner container with this command:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

my problem is when i want register gitlab-runner, runner ask me :

```
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
```

and me answer to that : http://localhost:80/ but it give me error :

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=K8trLPJx status=couldn't execute POST against http://localhost:80/api/v4/runners: Post http://localhost:80/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

2 container run on my pc whit windows 10

i dont want run gitlab-runner localy on my pc and i want docker to run it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are missing a network between the two containers. You could create it manually like this:

```
docker network create gitlab-network
```

And the let your containers join it with these commands:

```
docker network connect gitlab-network gitlab
docker network connect gitlab-network gitlab-runner
```

then you can pass as gitlab-ci coordinator URL just `gitlab`, as the name of the container is the is the dns on which the containers are reachable on docker networks.

Another solution, more elegant, is the usage of `docker-compose` to manage both of the containers and the network. Something like this, I haven't tested it:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    networks:
      - gitlab-network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    networks:
      - gitlab-network

networks:
  gitlab-network:
```

Comment: Gitlab-runner registration does not allow passing gitlab-ci coordinator URL just as `gitlab`. The following error will show `only http or https scheme supported`